# Why I can not see the panel in the homepage over the background picture?

Tags: html, css

In my project, I want to make a panel in the middle of my web homepage.

The panel is content div with white background color over the taiyi.jpg.

And there is four parts divs in the content div.

The web homepage code is like:

```
<body style="background:url(./image/taiyi.jpg); height:100%; width:100%;">
  <style>
  content{
    top:400px;
    left:400px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color:white;
  }
  .content .upleft, .downleft{
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
     float: left;
     background-color: red;
  }
  .content .upright, .downright{
     width: 250px;
     height: 250px;
     float: right;
     background-color: blue;
   }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
     $("#header").load("header_02.html");
   });
</script> 


<div id="header"></div>    
<div class="content">
  <div class="upleft"></div>
  <div class="upright"></div>
  <div class="downleft"></div>
  <div class="downright"></div>
</div>
<!--footer start-->
<div id="footer"></div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#footer").load("../footer_02.html");
});
</script>
<!--footer end-->
```

Now I have seen the blue and red divs. But I have not seen the content div with white Div.

I have tried:

```
content{
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color:white;
  }
```

and

```
content{
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color:white;
  }
```

But there are also fail. It seems nothing wrong, who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `content` in css as class

```
.content{ //put dot to determine that it's class
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:40px;
    width: 1600px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color:white;
  }
```